# Selecting single row for each employee with status_id by priroity

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

I need to extract only one record for each employee (`employee_id`) from `employee_leaves` table but only if `status_id` is equal to one of the following numbers: `7, 4, 3` (written by priority). When row with `status_id=7` has not been found, it should look for a row with `status_id=4`. When not found, it should look for row with `status_id=3`.

Example: row with id=4 should be returned

| id | employee_id | status_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 | 4 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 7 | 3 |
| 27 | 7 | 7 |

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) `select distinct...where status_id in (7,4,3)`, 2) `...order by status_id desc` 3) [limit 1](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT employee_id from employee_leaves where status_id = 7, or status_id =4, or status_id = 3   

Distinct is the word you were probably thinking about.

Comment: On what basis would you only select 1 row for employee 7 when there are 2 status = 7? Is it simply min(id)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need only one record for each employee but by prioritized status_id (get row with status_id=7 if exists, if not found then seek for status_id=4, if not found then seek for status_id=3. In my example above I would get fourth row (ID = 7 ... because it matches status_priority). Also there is ID=27 row that also matches but I need only one row that does match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the rows of each `employee_id` for the `status_id`s that you want.
Then rank the rows with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function by applying the priorities that you want.
Finally pick the first row from each ranking:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY employee_id
           ORDER BY status_id = 7 DESC,
                    status_id = 4 DESC,
                    status_id = 3 DESC, -- this is the last option and it is actually not needed
                    id
         ) AS rn 
  FROM employee_leaves 
  WHERE status_id IN (7, 4, 3)
)
SELECT id, employee_id, status_id 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause inside `ROW_NUMBER()` may be simplified with the use of function [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
ORDER BY FIELD(status_id, 7, 4, 3),
         id
```

or the function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status_id, '7,4,3'),
         id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/19B4_SjR).